# Is the Event Creator Field an Array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-events

The [FQL event object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) has a field called Creator. That is described as:

```
"Creator of the event"
```

It is also noted:

```
"This field is indexable"
```

Does the creator field really just return the user who initially created the event or does it return an array of event hosts?

Answer (score 0):

It will return a single User ID of the creator of the respective Event.